# Regex in Python to detect ellipsis

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-processing

I have a large text corpus that I want to process a little bit and then train a Word2Vec model based on it. There are cases that words are deleted due to ellipsis, like:

> But seeing them playing to *seven-* and *eight-year-olds* is beautiful

or

> The country was in the uproar of *pre-* and then *post-independence* civil war but the mood here is most often joyous

Now I want to undo these deletes (*inspired* and *second* respectively). This is what I wrote:

```
re.sub(r'- (and|to|or)( [^ -]+?){1,2}-(.+?)( |$|\n)', '-\\3 \\1\\2-\\3\\4', text)
```

But it doesn't work, since if there is more than one word between `and/or/to` and the second word with `-`, only the first will be shown.
My desired outputs are:

> But seeing them playing to *seven-year-olds* and *eight-year-olds* is beautiful

and

> The country was in the uproar of *pre-independence* and then *post-independence* civil war but the mood here is most often joyous

Comment: Please add explicit desired output for your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\b-(\s+(?:and|to|or)(?:\s+\w+)*\s+\w+(-\w[\w-]*))', r'\2\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OweCR8/1). *Details*:

- `\b-` - a hyphen that is preceded with a word char
- `(\s+(?:and|to|or)(?:\s+\w+)*\s+\w+(-\w[\w-]*))` - Group 1:

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:and|to|or)` - `and`, `to` or `or`
  - `(?:\s+\w+)*` - zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more word chars
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars
  - `(-\w[\w-]*)` - Group 2: a hyphen, a word char and then zero or more word or hyphen chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mUZg48):

```py
import re
texts = ['But seeing them playing to seven- and eight-year-olds is beautiful', 'The country was in the uproar of pre- and then post-independence civil war but the mood here is most often joyous']
rx = r''
for text in texts:
    print( re.sub(r'- (and|to|or)((?: [^ -]+?){1,2})-(.+?)( |$|\n)', '-\\3 \\1\\2-\\3\\4', text) )
```

Output:

```
But seeing them playing to seven-year-olds and eight-year-olds is beautiful
The country was in the uproar of pre-independence and then post-independence civil war but the mood here is most often joyous
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution:

```
re.sub(r'- (and|to|or)((?: [^ -]+?){1,2})-(.+?)( |$|\n)', '-\\3 \\1\\2-\\3\\4', text)
```